# How to make specific words in a Textview Clickable

Tags: android, textview, clickable

I have:

```
String desc="Drugs in this section include antimuscarinic compounds (section 4.3) and drugs believed to be direct relaxants of intestinal smooth muscle. The smooth muscle relaxant properties of antimuscarinic(section 4.4) and other antispasmodic drugs may be useful in irritable bowel syndrome(section 4.5) and in diverticular disease.The dopamine-receptor antagonists metoclopramide and domperidone (section 4.6) stimulate transit in the gut.";
```

I want to make `(section 4.3)`, `(section 4.4)`, `(section 4.5)`, `(section 4.6)` **clickable** with different click targets.

How can I implement it?